# jQuery moving MultiSelect values to another MultiSelect

Tags: jquery, select

So I have a MultiSelect box with x values which I need the ability to move to another MultiSelect box and vise versa.

```
<select class="boxa" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class="boxb" multiple="multiple">

</select>
```

Need to move all or one of the values of boxa to boxb on a button click, also with the ability to move the values back from boxb to boxa.

Does jQuery have anything like this or is this a custom snippet of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a jquery plugin called [crossSelect](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/crossSelect) which seems to do what you want.

jQuery doesn't have this built in, you would need to either find a plugin you like and use that, or write your own.  (And of course you don't *have* to use jQuery to write or use it, you could implement it in pure javascript if you like)

Comment: Aforementioned link is dead now.

Answer (score 74):

```
$().ready(function() {  
 $('#add').click(function() {  
  return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
 });  
 $('#remove').click(function() {  
  return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
 });  
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer -- works perfectly with no plugin required.

Comment: What is the return  and the ! for?

Comment: @alonso.torres that is for returning false, from http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html: _To prevent the page from scrolling to the top whenever a user clicks a button (in some browsers), I added return false; to the click event handlers._

Answer (score 10):

Try the following
(taken from http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html)

```
<html>  
<head>  
 <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">  
  $().ready(function() {  
   $('#add').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
   });  
   $('#remove').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
   });  
  });  
 </script>  

 <style type="text/css">  
  a {  
   display: block;  
   border: 1px solid #aaa;  
   text-decoration: none;  
   background-color: #fafafa;  
   color: #123456;  
   margin: 2px;  
   clear:both;  
  }  
  div {  
   float:left;  
   text-align: center;  
   margin: 10px;  
  }  
  select {  
   width: 100px;  
   height: 80px;  
  }  
 </style>  

</head>  

<body>  
 <div>  
  <select multiple id="select1">  
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>  
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>  
  </select>  
  <a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</a>  
 </div>  
 <div>  
  <select multiple id="select2"></select>  
  <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</a>  
 </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Very simple solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Silas!

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem  but i found out a way around it

```
<div>
    <select multiple id="select1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select multiple id="select2"></select>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#select1').click(function () {
     return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
});

$('#select2').click(function () {
     return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
 });
```

if want a button add a add >> 
and jquery click selector here

example http://jsfiddle.net/diffintact/GJJQw/3/

Comment: This looks like a copy of Yashita's answer

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#boxa option').appendTo('#boxb');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with plugin, this plugin does work well.

http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/#home

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one time selection and form submission quick solution to add and remove options between two selects on click.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.onclickaddto', function(e){
    var to  = $(this).attr('data-to');
    $(this).find('option:selected').remove().appendTo($(to)); 
});
```

```css
.multiselect{
    width: 98%;
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:flex;">
   <div style="width:50%;">
        <h2>Enabled countries</h2>
          <select name="allowed_countries[]" class="onclickaddto multiselect" data-to="#available_countries" id="allowed_countries" multiple=""></select>
    </div>
    
    <div style="width:50%">
        <h2>Available countries</h2>
            <select class="onclickaddto multiselect" id="available_countries" data-to="#allowed_countries" multiple="">
                <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
        </select>
     </div>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my html code

```
<div>
        <select multiple id="select1">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" id="add">add &gt; &gt;</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select multiple id="select2"></select>
        <a href="#" id="remove">remove &lt; &lt;</a>
    </div>
```

and Javascript code

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#select1 option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#select2"));
})
$("#remove").click(function(){
    $("#select2 option:selected").remove().appendTo($("#select1"));
})
```

Make sure you imported `jquery.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

If using Bootstrap, I found [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) quite handy.

- Filterable
- Responsive
- Localizable
- Highly customizable
- Seems well maintained