# adding selection from one text box to another using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 textbox horizontally. In 1st textbox I have a drop down of lists where I can select multiple list.  I have a add button in middle of those two text boxes. If I will click on add button by selecting from that textbox that selected list should appear in second text box. .. how I can do that. Please help me out? ?

Comment: Place your code. Some code would definitely promote an answer

Comment: Share your HTML snippet

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery moving MultiSelect values to another MultiSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356903/456814),

> ```
> $().ready(function() {  
>  $('#add').click(function() {  
>   return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
>  });  
>  $('#remove').click(function() {  
>   return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
>  });  
> });
> ```

Comment: check his link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058517/jquery-moving-multiselect-values-to-another-multiselect

Comment: When you copy someone else's answer, make sure you quote and link to it, otherwise you are basically plagiarizing them.