# Dynamically add objects to list from dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to try and put this in the simplest terms and hopefully someone can help me.  I'm new to MVC and i'm trying to learn the ropes.

I have an dropdown that is populated with tenant objects.

I want a user to be able to select a tenant in the drop down, and have that tenant added to a list (Enumerable of Tenant objects) and displayed below the dropdown in a section called "Added Tenants" while also removing the selected tenant from the dropdown.

I don't want these tenants added to the database until later because this is a form creating a lease, and i want them to finish filling out the rest of the lease and create it all at once.

I'm hoping someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction.  Yes i have done searches but haven't found anything yet that will help me or that i understood.

Edit:  The list can be of object, just an id, or even a select list. The end game is to use that list to add them to the collection which is a 1 to many relationship.  That list will also be used to populate partial views with the tenant information, kind of like how the tags work in stack overflow.

Comment: You will need javascript/query to handle client side events. But you ight find this easier just to use a listbox or a checkboxlist of all tenants so that the values will post back without need any javascript to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not clear what the "list" is that you want added to (i.e. a UL or a form select list), but this solution is going to be done in javascript, not ASP.

Try doing a few searches on SO.  Such as:

[jQuery moving MultiSelect values to another MultiSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058517/jquery-moving-multiselect-values-to-another-multiselect)

Comment: The list at this point can be and object of tenants, or just a list of id's.  After having that list i'm pretty sure i can handle the rest with a partial view that loads the tenant information to display a name.  And yeah i figured i would need some javascript for this, i'll take a look at what you posted.